# Login using Private key on USB Dongle on SSH@linux

Tags: linux, ssh, usb, authentication, certificates

I'm presently using PPK file (public and private key pair) generated from putty to Login (password less) through  ssh in Linux server and it is working well.

I am exploring possibility in using my Private key stored in USB Dongle(trust key) to do the same.

Please guide.